# Add content in-between child elements on each row on a responsive parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a list:

```
<style>
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div>Apple</div>
  <div>Banana</div>
  <div>Cherry</div>
  <div>Durian</div>
  <div>Mango</div>
  <div>Pear</div>
</div>
```

Now depending on the `width` of `#container`, I would want it so that `•` appears only *in-between* the items on each line.

For example:

```
# Full-width (all on one line)

Apple • Banana • Cherry • Durian • Mango • Pear
```

```
# Half-width (on two lines)
Apple • Banana • Cherry
Durian • Mango • Pear
```

```
# Min-width (on three lines)
Apple • Banana
Cherry • Durian
Mango • Pear
```

How can I achieve this? Is there a JavaScript-free solution?

Comment: Please read ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting here. Then, if you do post, we expect that you'll post what you've tried, along with a specific question about the code. We are not a tutorial site or a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can set another wrapper and use `negative margin` and `overflow: hidden`. Using this trick to hide unwanted bullet point and achieve what you need.

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;            
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#container div{
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#container div::before{
    content: "•";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="container">
        <div>Apple</div>
        <div>Banana</div>
        <div>Cherry</div>
        <div>Durian</div>
        <div>Mango</div>
        <div>Pear</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the *"depending on the width of #container, I would want it so that • appears only in-between the items on each line."* part of the question. Also, we really don't like to provide answers to poor questions as it just attracts more poor questions. This question is poor because the OP hasn't made any attempt at a solution.

Comment: First of all, it perfectly works the way OP addressed if you can check correctly. And secondly, it is an interesting question where the OP showed his code and his expectations very clearly. He didn't just show an image and asked "I want this". And I saw enormous amount of questions on Stack Overflow where OP didn't show his attempt but still many experienced users were answering and commenting to give a solution because they are not just asking codes rather they are asking for a solution to a particular problem which can be helpful for others as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the snippet in this answer does demonstrate a responsive solution which works. However, I do agree that the question needs to demonstrate that some research has been done, and therefore perhaps it would have been better to wait before giving an answer.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam *"it perfectly works the way OP addressed if you can check correctly."* <-- No, it doesn't. There's nothing in your code that addresses different renderings based on viewport size. It shows a "fluid" design that doesn't address the "full width", "half width" and "min width" scenarios that the OP discusses. Also, please don't judge whether your answer is appropriate based on what you've seen others do. Stack Overflow has guidelines on How to Ask questions. Since this OP didn't make any attempt at solving the issue, it's not a good question and we should refrain from answering.

Comment: @BrettDonald The above answer does not show a *responsive* solution as it uses flexbox to create a fluid design, where the layout doesn't change (or respond) to different viewport sizes. It simply scales the layout. But, more to the point, since the OP hasn't made an attempt at a solution, it's not a good question and we shouldn't answer poor questions because it just attracts more poor questions.

Comment: For everyone's benefit, CSS Media Queries are the way to accomplish what the OP is asking about.